# Using Column in 'Case when' without including in Group By - or use partition over

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following are two tables. And I have also shown required Output below.

**TABLE A**

```
+------------+--------------+
| InvoiceNo. | InvoiceTotal |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 |          190 |
|          2 |          360 |
|          3 |          170 |
|          4 |          269 |
|          5 |           30 |
+------------+--------------+
```

**TABLE B**

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----------+
| InvoiceNo. |   TaxName    | Tax% | TaxAmount |
+------------+--------------+------+-----------+
|          1 | State 5%     |    5 | 9.5       |
|          1 | Local  5%    |    5 | 9.5       |
|          1 | State 7%     |    7 | 13.3      |
|          1 | Local  7%    |    7 | 13.3      |
|          2 | National 10% |   10 | 36        |
|          3 | State 4%     |    4 | 6.8       |
|          3 | Local  4%    |    4 | 6.8       |
|          4 | State 6%     |    6 | 16.14     |
|          4 | Local  6%    |    6 | 16.14     |
|          5 | National 14% |   14 | 4.2       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----------+
```

**Required OUTPUT**

Group By (InvoiceNo, Tax%), and Sum(Tax%, TaxAmount)
But

If TaxName is like 'State' or 'Local' then goes to "State+Local " Column with Sum of State+Local Tax%
If TaxName is like "National" then goes to "National" Column

```
+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+----------------+
| InvoiceNo | InvoiceTotal | State+Local | National | State+Local_Amount | NationalAmount |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+----------------+
|         1 |          120 |          10 |        0 | 19                 | 0              |
|         1 |          120 |          14 |        0 | 26.6               | 0              |
|         2 |          360 |           0 |       10 | 0                  | 36             |
|         3 |           85 |           8 |        0 | 13.6                | 0              |
|         4 |          269 |          12 |        0 | 32.28              | 0              |
|         5 |           30 |           0 |       14 | 0                  | 4.2            |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+----------------+
```

**Following is what i am doing**

```
CREATE TABLE #tableA(InvoiceNo varchar(100), InvoiceTotal float)
insert into #tableA values
('1',190),  
('2',360),  
('3',170),  
('4',269),  
('5',30)


CREATE TABLE #tableB(InvoiceNo varchar(100), TaxName varchar(25), TaxPercentile float, TaxAmount float)
INSERT INTO #tableB VALUES
('1','State 5%',5, 9.5),
('1','Local 5%',5, 9.5),
('1','State 7%',7, 13.3),
('1','Local 7%',7, 13.3),
('2','National 10%',10, 36),
('3','State 4%',4, 6.8),
('3','Local 4%',4, 6.8),
('4','State 6%',6, 16.14),
('4','Local 6%',6, 16.14),
('5','National 14%',14, 4.2)



select B.InvoiceNo, A.InvoiceTotal, 
case when TaxName like '%State%' or TaxName like '%Local%' then sum(b.TaxPercentile) else 0 End as [StateLocal], 
case when TaxName like '%National%' then sum(b.TaxPercentile) else 0 End as [National],
case when TaxName like '%State%' or TaxName like '%Local%' then sum(b.TaxAmount) else 0 End as [StateLocal_Amount], 
case when TaxName like '%National%' then sum(b.TaxAmount) else 0 End as [NationalAmount]
from #tableB B
Left join #TableA A on a.InvoiceNo = b.InvoiceNo
Group by b.InvoiceNo, A.InvoiceTotal 
-- if i include "TaxName" in group by then it does not returns required output
-- if i do not include "TaxName" in Group by then it gives error saying i have to include TaxName in group by
```

If I include "TaxName" in group by then it does not returns required output.

If I do not include "TaxName" in Group by then it gives error saying I have to include TaxName in group by.

Can it be done by using Partition over in case when statement? If yes how or is what is other way around?

Comment: Turn it inside out: `sum(case when TaxName like '%State%'  ...)`

Comment: why do you want two rows for InvoiceNo 1? Also invoiceTotal should be 120 in TableA

Comment: The numbers in your sample input and output seriously don't agree with each other.  Please fix your data.

Comment: @biegeleisen , sorry for wrong . I updated and made it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your query:

```
with taxes as (
select invoiceNo,
       round(sum(case when taxname like 'State%' or taxname like 'Local%' then taxpercentile else 0 end), 2) 'State+Local', 
       round(sum(case when taxname like 'National%' then taxpercentile else 0 end), 2) 'National',
       round(sum(case when taxname like 'State%' or taxname like 'Local%' then taxamount else 0 end), 2) 'State+Local_Amount',
       round(sum(case when taxname like 'National%' then taxamount else 0 end), 2) 'National_Amount'
from tableb
group by invoiceno
)
    select a.*, t.*
      from tablea a
inner join taxes t 
        on a.invoiceno = t.invoiceno
```

You can check it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3ecfb/14).

Answer (score -1):

try like below I have added aggregation also on   `InvoiceTotal`

```
   select B.InvoiceNo, sum(A.InvoiceTotal), 
   sum( case when TaxName like '%State%' or TaxName like '%Local%'
      then   b.TaxPercentile else 0 End) as [StateLocal], 
   sum(case when TaxName like '%National%' 
   then (b.TaxPercentile) else 0 End) as [National],
   sum( case when TaxName like '%State%' or TaxName like '%Local%'
      then b.TaxAmount else 0 End )as [StateLocal_Amount], 
   sum(case when TaxName like '%National%' 
    then b.TaxAmount else 0 End ) as [NationalAmount]
    from #tableB B
    Left join #TableA A on a.InvoiceNo = b.InvoiceNo
    Group by b.InvoiceNo
```